# Auto deployment of ASP.NET Core React application fails with: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, azure, azure-deployment

I have a pretty standard ASP.NET Core application. It's an React app.

I deploy the application through the `Deployment options` inside Azure, whenever I make a push to Github.

Just recently, however, I started getting the error: `Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3`

This started happening after I made the following commit:

[image]

Or my updated `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Likvido.CreditRisk",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/react": "15.0.35",
    "@types/react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "3.2.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

**So my challenge**: how do I fix this?

I am aware that after installing the `react-bootstrap-typeahead`, it probably installed the `fsevents` package.

However, it works perfectly locally. When I publish through the standard Publish inside Visual Studio it works.

Any ideas what I should do to get it to work from the auto deployment in Azure?

**Error in Activity Log**:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk.csproj...
  Restore completed in 6.61 sec for D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk.csproj.
  Restore completed in 1.28 min for D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk.csproj.
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.6.82.30579 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 381.1 ms for D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk.csproj.
  Restore completed in 440.47 ms for D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk.csproj.
  Likvido.CreditRisk -> D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Likvido.CreditRisk.dll
  Likvido.CreditRisk@0.0.1 D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk
  +-- @types/react-bootstrap-typeahead@2.3.0 
  +-- chain-function@1.0.0 
  +-- classnames@2.2.5 
  +-- dom-helpers@3.3.1 
  +-- nan@2.9.2 
  +-- prop-types-extra@1.0.1 
  +-- react-bootstrap-typeahead@2.5.1 
  +-- react-onclickoutside@6.7.1 
  +-- react-overlays@0.8.3 
  `-- react-transition-group@2.2.1 

  npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
  npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\6.9.1\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.10.8\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
  npm ERR! node v6.9.1
  npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
  npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

  npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
  npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
  npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
  npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
  npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: ia32

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\npm-debug.log
D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk.csproj(62,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 1.
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk\Likvido.CreditRisk.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d58b5d12624ee6" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\71.10217.3259\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by upgrading node and then adding `"optional": true` to my npm-shrinkwrap.json under the fsevents entry. The entry looked like this:

```
"fsevents": {
  "version": "1.1.3",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.1.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-WIr7iDkdmdbxu/Gh6eKEZJL6KPE74/5MEsf2whTOFNxbIoIixogroLdKYqB6FDav4Wavh/lZdzzd3b2KxIXC5Q==",
  "dev": true,
  "optional": true,
... More stuff here
```